# Accessing className attribute in leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet

This seems trivial but I can't find the answer anywhere. I have set the className attribute of a circleMarker:

```
var marker = L.circleMarker([lat, lng], {
  radius: 6,
  color: 'black',
  weight: 2,
  opacity: 1,
  fillColor: 'red',
  fillOpacity: 1.0,
  className: 'redSpot'
}).addTo(map);
```

and I simply want to access the className property later on, something like:

```
marker.className
```

But this gives 'undefined' rather than 'redSpot'. Other attempts all give 'undefined':

```
marker.attr('className')
marker.data('className')
```

How do you access the className attribute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what the final story is on this, but in all versions of Leaflet I tested (0.7 - 1.0), the circleMarker class DOES NOT inherit the className option for its constructor...even though the docs said it should.  Weird.  I know the leaflet team has described caveats and bugs related to this option.

Try this.

```
var marker = L.circleMarker([lat, lng], {
  radius: 6,
  color: 'black',
  weight: 2,
  opacity: 1,
  fillColor: 'red',
  fillOpacity: 1.0
}).addTo(map);

marker.className = "redSpot";
```

Comment: Your solution works, thank you. But I don't understand: in the leaflet docs it says that circleMarker extends Marker, which extends Path. And className is viable option for Path. So why does the constructor not accept it?

Comment: I updated my answer reflecting this.  I thought it didn't have the option for the constructor at all, but you're right, the documentation seems to suggest that's an acceptable option.